# Matlab: How to add selected items in listbox?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have two listboxes:

'unselectedchannellistbox' contains all items as a (nx1) cell.
'selectedchannellistbox' is empty.

'selectchannels' is a pushbutton.

Now I want to add items from 'unselectedchannellistbox' to 'selectectedchannellistbox'. But I dont want to delete or overwrite the items!

This is my code:

```
function selectchannels_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Get selected item
listbox_strings = get(handles.unselectedchannellistbox,'String');
selected_value = get(handles.unselectedchannellistbox,'Value');
S = num2cell(selected_value);

for k = 1:length(S)
    S(end+1) = {get(handles.unselectedchannellistbox,'Value')};
end

set(handles.selectedchannellistbox,'String',selected_value)
```

Unfortunately, adding another element to my new cell array (S) with (end+1) and get(handles.unselectedchannellistbox,'Value') doesn't work.

What's going wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

Micha

Comment: Please specify _doesn't work_. Error message? Wrong result? ...

Comment: It was the wrong result... the items in Listbox2 has been overwritten so there was always only one entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it!! This works perfectly for me:

```
function selectchannels_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Get selected item
listbox_strings = get(handles.unselectedchannellistbox,'String');
selected_value = get(handles.unselectedchannellistbox,'Value');
S = listbox_strings{selected_value};

set(handles.selectedchannellistbox,'String', ...
      [get(handles.selectedchannellistbox, 'String'); {S}]);
```

Thanks a lot for your help!